# print logs from Kubernetes api

Tags: python, api, python-requests, kubernetes

I was wondering if there is a possibility to continuously print logs from HTTP request to Kubernetes API. I am using python for querying K8S API sth like

`r = requests.get(self.url + "namespaces/" + namespace + "/pods/" + pod_name + "/log", cert=(self.cert, self.key), verify=False)`

and i would like to use `follow=true` parameter probably together with `tailLines=100` to make it more like `tail` command.

When I am using `follow` parameter the request is collecting response but i don't know how to forward it's output to console.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

What i was missing is `stream=True` in `request.get` parameter which allows to iterate through the response content so my code looks like this:

```
import requests

class Logs():
    def __init__(self, url='https://192.168.0.1:6443/api/v1/',
                 cert='./client.crt',
                 key='./client.key'):
        self.url = url
        self.cert = cert
        self.key = key
        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

    def get_pod_logs(self, namespace, pod_name):

        params = dict(
            follow="true",
            tailLines="100"
        )

        r = requests.get(self.url + "namespaces/" + namespace + "/pods/" + pod_name + "/log", params=params,
                         cert=(self.cert, self.key), verify=False, stream=True)

        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=256):
            if chunk:
                print(chunk)

logs = Logs()

logs.get_pod_logs(namespace="my-ns",pod_name="my-pod")
```

Answer (score -1):

You're almost there. I think what you want is the following:

```
kubectl logs -f <your-pod-name> --tail=100
```

You can get pod names with the following command:

```
kubectl get pods
```

Hope that helps

Comment: i know `kubectl` binary but i want to create some simple script for other users which will allow them to tail logs from their own computers. I know that there is possibility to configure `kubectl` locally but i want to play a little with python :)